# Call a PHP file from the main file

Tags: php

I want to arrange my codes properly by starting to separate the codes like uploading files, from the index.php, How can i call the upload.php in the index.php? The upload.php is not a function. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<?php include('upload.php');?>` at the top of index.php

Comment: Might also want to mention the fact that you can use `require()` and/or `include_once()`/`require_once()`. There is no real difference between include and require (only upon failure, the require would throw a different error). However there is a difference between include/require and include_once/require_once. The _once() methods would check if the file has already been included, if it has, it would not include it again.

Comment: Just for info - if <code>include()</code> fails then an error will generate but the rest of the code will continue to execute, if <code>require()</code> fails then a fatal error will generate and your code execution will stop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

require_once 'upload.php';

//no close tag if you have no html code
```